# How to design a struct to work with references when it can be initialized either via an API or from a file?

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker, ownership

## Context

I am trying to build a Rust library with an implementation of a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). The automaton is represented as a struct `DFA<'a, A>`, where the generic type `A` represents the symbols being read by the automaton. I want users to be able to initialize `DFA` structs in two different ways:

1. Programmatically, using an intermediate `DFABuilder` API
2. From a DFA definition file

## Problem

I want the implementation to not be wasteful of memory, so I am trying to have as few owned types as possible, and am trying to never use the `.clone()` method. This is where the problem appears due to the two different methods of initialization.

### 1. Initializing via an API

In this situation, I can assume that the calling code owns the values representing the states (`String` type) and the symbols (`A` type), so my code can only take references to it (`&str` and `&A`, respectively). As long as the calling code lives, the references are valid.

### 2. Initializing from a definition file

In this situation, it is the code within the library that reads the file, and constructs the `DFA` internally, also using the `DFABuilder`. However, the issue here is that all the `DFABuilder` methods expect *references* to the generic type `A`. But I cannot pass references, because the values they refer to go out of scope when the file reading function ends.

What is the best way to design the `DFA<'a, A>` and `DFABuilder<'a, A>` structs, as well as the fields within them, so that I can utilize references as much as possible while also  being able to initialize `DFA` structs both via an API and from a file?

## Current code

I am attaching the skeleton of the code I currently have below. Note that the state is internally represented as a `u32` type - this is because in the build process I encode states by enumerating them, so that I don't have to work with neither `String`s nor `&str`s.

```rust
pub struct DFA<'a, A> {
  accept_set: HashSet<u32>,
  start_state: u32,
  current_state: Option<u32>,
  transitions: HashMap<(u32, &A), u32>
}

impl<'a, A> DFA {
  // Feed a sequence of symbols to the DFA
  // Returns whether the sequence is accepted
  pub fn feed_sequence(&mut self, &[A]) -> bool {...}
  // Feed a single symbol to the DFA
  pub fn feed_symbol(&mut self, &A) {...}
}

pub struct DFABuilder<'a, A> {
  string2state: HashMap<&'a str, u32>,

  states: Vec<u32>,
  alphabet: &'a[&'a A],
  accept: HashSet<u32>,
  start: u32,
  transitions: HashMap<(u32, &'a A), u32>
}

impl<'a, A> DFABuilder {
  pub fn with_states(mut self, states: &'a[&'a str]) -> DFABuilder<'a, A> {
    // compute string2state encoding
    // encode states with string2state
    // store encoded states in self
  }
  
  pub fn with_alphabet(mut self, alphabet: &'a[&'a A]) -> DFABuilder<'a, A> {...}

  pub fn with_accept(mut self, states: &'a[&'a str]) -> DFABuilder<'a, A> {
    // encode states with string2state
    // store encoded accept states in self
  }

  pub fn with_start(mut self, state: &'a str) -> DFABuilder<'a, A> {
    // encode state with string2state
    // store encoded start state in self
  }

  pub fn with_transition(mut self, transition: (&'a str, &'a A, &'a str)) -> DFABuilder<'a, A> {...}

  pub fn build(self) -> DFA<'a, A> {...}

}

pub fn from_file<A: FromStr>(path: &str) -> DFA<'a, A> {
  // Reads and parses the file into Vec<String> / Vec<A> types,
  // and then uses DFABuilder to build a DFA.
  // 
  // PROBLEM:
  // This function necessarily owns the underlying `String` and `A` values
  // so I can't pass a reference to them into DFABuilder, because they don't
  // live long enough.
  // I could redefine the DFABuilder API to take in owned values,
  // but that means the calling code would lose ownership when
  // initializing via an API.
}
```

For reference, this is how the definition file looks like:

```
# Full state set Q, separated by spaces
s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6
# Full alphabet A, separated by spaces
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
# Start state
s1
# Acceptable states, separated by spaces
s5 s6
# List of 0 or more transitions in format STATE SYMBOL STATE
s1 0 s2
s1 1 s3
s1 2 s1
s1 7 s6
...
```

Essentially, my question is:
*What would be the best practice in designing a library like this? How to keep the library memory light, while providing an intuitive API for clients, and enabling initialization from files?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to just use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) for the data, or a custom similar enum if `Cow` is not good enough for your needs. Assuming `A` is large, this adds little memory overhead, but it can worsen execution speed and if `A` is small (e.g. a character) it can even double the memory usage.

The hard solution is to use a self-referential struct. Read the file into a backing storage of `A`s, then refer to this backing storage in the same struct. This is safe even when the struct moves because the data will be behind an indirection (e.g. `Vec`). Self-referential structs are hard, but libraries like  [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros) can ease the process and make it unsafe-free. Note that this will not help if `A` is small: it will still double memory usage. If this is a problem for you, you likely need to create two structs: one borrowed and one owned. You can probably create one generic struct too.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I expect that in the vast majority of cases, `A` would be very small - most likely a `char`, one of the integer types, or a short `String`. So it seems I will have to go (1) with the two-struct solution, (2) somehow make current struct do both, or (3) just go with owned fields and try to minimize their footprint.

Comment: @Gloripaxis You can probably make the struct generic over `Borrow<A>`.